# ¿Cómo concatenar cadenas de carácteres sin usar la función strcat?

Tags: c

Muy buenas, necesito saber, dados dos strings introducidos por el usuario, cómo concatenarlos.

Mi código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CMAX 50

int longitud_paraula (char paraula []);
void copia_paraula (char paraula_desti [], char paraula_origen []);
int comparacio_paraula (char paraula1 [], char paraula2 []);
void concatenar_paraula (char paraula_desti [], char paraula_origen []);

    void main () {

        char paraula [19], paraula_origen [19], paraula_desti [19], paraula1 [19], paraula2 [19];
        int res, n;

        n = 1;

        while (n!=0) {
            printf ("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            printf ("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n\n");
            printf ("1.- Introduir una paraula.\n");
            printf ("2.- Mostrar la paraula.\n");
            printf ("3.- Saber la longitud de la paraula.\n");
            printf ("4.- Donada una nova paraula, copiarla en una altre.\n");
            printf ("5.- Donada dos noves paraules, dir quina és més gran, més petita o si és igual.\n");
            printf ("6.- Concatena dues paraules.\n");
            printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf ("\nOpció a escollir: ");            
            scanf ("%d", &n);
            getchar ();

            switch (n) {

                case 1: 
                    system ("clear");
                    printf ("Introdueix la paraula: ");
                    scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    system ("clear");                   
                    printf ("Paraula: %s\n", paraula);
                    break;  

                case 3:
                    system ("clear");
                    res = longitud_paraula (paraula);                       
                    printf ("La longitud de la paraula és: %d\n", res);                 
                    break;

                case 4:
                    system ("clear");
                    printf ("Introdueix una nova paraula per copiar: ");
                    scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula_origen);
                    getchar ();
                    copia_paraula (paraula_desti, paraula_origen);
                    printf ("Paraula copiada: %s\n", paraula_desti);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    system ("clear");
                    printf ("Introdueix la paraula a comparar: ");
                    scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula1);
                    getchar ();
                    printf ("Introdueix la segona paraula a comparar: ");
                    scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula2);
                    getchar ();
                    res = comparacio_paraula (paraula1, paraula2);
                    if (res == 1) {
                        printf ("La primera paraula és major que la segona paraula.");
                    }
                    if (res == -1) {
                        printf ("La primera paraula és menor que la segona paraula.");
                    }
                        if (res == 0) {
                        printf ("La primera paraula és igual que la segona paraula.");
                    }
                    break;

                case 6:
                    system ("clear");
                    printf ("Introdueix la paraula a concatenar: ");
                    scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula_origen);
                    getchar ();
                    printf ("Introdueix la segona paraula a concatenar: ");
                    scanf ("%[^\n]", paraula_desti);
                    getchar ();
                    concatenar_paraula (paraula_origen, paraula_desti);
                    printf ("Paraula: %s", paraula_concatenada);
            }
        }    
    }

    // Funció número 1.

    int longitud_paraula (char paraula []) {
        int i, cont, cont_espais;
            cont_espais = 0;
            i = 0;
            cont = 0;
            while (paraula [i] != '\0') {
                if (paraula [i] == ' ') {
                    cont_espais ++;
                }
                i ++;
                cont ++;
            }
        cont = cont - cont_espais;
        return (cont);
    }

    // Funció número 2.

    void copia_paraula (char paraula_desti [], char paraula_origen []) {
        int i;
            i = 0;
            while ((paraula_origen [i] != '\0') && (i < CMAX)) {
                paraula_desti [i] = paraula_origen [i];
                i ++;
            }
    }

    // Funció número 3.

    int comparacio_paraula (char paraula1 [], char paraula2 []) {
        int i, comparacio;
        i = 0;
        while (((paraula1 [i] != '\0') && (paraula2 [i] != '\0') && (paraula1 [i] = paraula2 [i] ))) {
            i ++;
        }
        if (paraula1 [i] > paraula2 [i]){
            comparacio = 1;
        }
        if (paraula1 [i] < paraula2 [i]) {
            comparacio = -1;
        }
        if (paraula1 [i] == paraula2 [i]) {
            comparacio = 0;
        }
        return (comparacio);
    }

    // Funció número 4.

    void concatenar_paraula (char paraula_desti [], char paraula_origen []) {
        printf ("Paraula: %s\n%s\n", paraula_origen, paraula_desti);            
    }
```

En este caso, pongamos que la primera palabra que introduce el usuario es: "Hola" y la segunda "amigo". Así pues, debería mostrarme Holaamigo.

Pero el problema es que no sé cómo puedo hacerlo.

De antemano, gracias.

PD: Es el case número 6 y la función número 4.

Comment: No soy experto en c, pero ¿porqué no usas sprintf? char str[80]; sprintf(str, "%s%s", paraula_origen, paraula_desti); printf("%s", str);

Comment: Es que te cuento, en clase nos hacen hacer como las funciones típicas de copiar, concatenar, contar la longitud, usando funciones. Y claro, no podemos usar la función original, si no una versión echa por nosotros.
Es pero eso que pregunto como hacerlo.
Sobre lo de sprintf, nunca lo he hecho, así que no creo que valga jeje. ¿Conoces otra manera?

Comment: @AlexIglesias ¿Entonces no es válido utilizar memoria dinámica?

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, no sabemos la longitud de cada cadena que *lees*, así que ese es un fallo bastante grande... en segundo lugar, ¿Por qué no utilizar la función `strcat`? Si lo que intentas es aprender el funcionamiento interno de la función, entonces deberías intentar crearla y luego acudir aquí con un problema en tu implementación.

En tercer lugar, no sabemos si usas memoria dinámica en tu ejemplo, por lo que no se si es válido utilizar `realloc` en la solución, así que me he quedado con esta implementación rápida *(La he hecho en 3 minutos, no me juzguen)*:

```
char *cat(char *s1, char *s2) {
  if (!s1 || !s2)
    return s1? s1: s2;

  int len = strlen(s1), len2 = strlen(s2);
  s1 = realloc(s1, (len + len2));
  for (int i = 0; i < (len + len2); i++)
    s1[i + len] = s2[i];
  s1[len + len2] = 0;
  return s1;
}
```

Lo que hace la función arriba es simplemente verificar que ambos `char *` tengan contenido, si uno de los dos no tiene contenido, se retorna el otro, posteriormente, consigue la longitud de ambas cadenas y "pon" o "pega" los caracteres al final de la cadena.

Esta solución altera el contenido del primer argumento y retorna el mismo por igual.

Y te dejo este `main()` para que lo pruebes.

```
int main(void) {
  char *T = malloc(20);
  memcpy(T, "hello", 5);
  printf("Antes de concatenar: '%s'\n", T);
  char *T2 = cat(T, " world");
  printf("Despues de concatenar: '%s'\n", T);
  return 0;
}
```

Recuerda siempre hacer los includes de `stdlib.h` y `string.h` para las funciones de copiado y colocado de memoria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

El código completo me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Antes de concatenar: 'hello'
Despues de concatenar: 'hello world'
```

Otra posible solución al respecto _(Como menciona [track3r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146607/c%c3%b3mo-concatenar-cadenas-de-car%c3%a1cteres-sin-usar-la-funci%c3%b3n-strcat#comment274991_146607) es usar `sprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char Buffer[50] = "Hola";
  printf("Buffer antes: %s\n", Buffer);
  sprintf(Buffer, "%s%s", Buffer, "amigo");
  printf("Buffer despues: %s\n", Buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Este último arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Buffer antes: Hola
Buffer despues: Holaamigo
```

Saludos :)

Comment: Gracias por responder, te cuento:
Encima del main tengo `#define CMAX 50` para establecer un máximo.
Lo de memoria dinámica no sé lo que es jeje.
Y lo de que por qué no he intentado hacerlo, sí que lo he intentado pero es que no sé como empezar, he visto así por encima el ejercicio de los compañeros de clase y empiezan a hacer fors para hacerlo.

Y claro, no debería usar sprintf, si no que debería hacerlo en plan más rudimentario jeje, no sé si me entiendes.

Comment: Entonces deberías ingresar el código que has intentado para concatenar ambas cadenas _a mano_, de esa forma podemos ayudarte a resolver el problema con tu propio código!

Comment: He editado mi pregunta y he puesto todo mi código, es la función número 4 y el case número 6, pero como te he dicho, es que no sé cómo empezar, lo siento :(

Comment: Piensa @AlexIglesias.. que harias si fueran todos cuadraditos de papel? a veces la soluciones es mas manual que de sistemas.

Comment: Bueno, le ayudo un poco con el algoritmo: Obten la longitud de la primera cadena y empieza a poner caracteres a partir de ahí, si es que me entiendes :^)

Comment: ¿Quieres que cuenta la longitud de la primera palabra y después introduzca más caracteres?
¿Te refieres a hacer algo así como `palabra_origen = palabra_origen + palabra_destino`?
Sé que esto es incorrecto, pero es la única forma que se me ocurre.

Comment: Mira, en C, las cadenas de texto terminan con un caracter nulo o `0`, para obtener la longitud de la cadena, itera sobre ella utilizando un contador, algo como: `int i = 0; while (cadena[i] != 0) i++;` y luego empieza a escribir asi: `int j = 0; while (cadena2[j] != 0) cadena[i + j] = cadena2[j], j++;` y listo, cuentanos por donde tienes problemas :)

Comment: Sí, eso precisamente lo hago en la función número 1, saber la longitud del string. Pero no quiero saber la longitud, quiero saber como concatenar dos palabras para mostrar la unión de estas.

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Te lo he respondido ahí en el comentario anterior, no te estoy diciendo "como buscar la longitud", lo que te digo es que necesitas saber donde se encuentra el ultimo caracter para empezar a escribir los caracteres a concatenar a partir de ese índice.